# Tomcat on Window: Can't connect from remote machine

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat

I have a windows vista :( machine that I have installed Tomcat on. I changed the server.xml so that it connects on 80 instead of 8080. I can hit the server locally by going to anyone of the following:

1. localhost
2. 127.0.0.1
3. 192.168.1.3

From remote devices that are on the same router, I can ping the machine by it's IP, but I can't connect to the server.

In the router I set up portforwarding on 80 to 192.168.1.3

I have turned off windows firewall and windows defender to avoid problems there. No other antivirus. Anyone know what I can try to connect to this thing?

Comment: What error do you get when you try 192.168.1.3 in a browser from a remote device? Do you get a 404?

Comment: Providing the error would help as mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to setup port forwarding on the router so that any traffic coming in on port 80 is automatically forwarded to 192.168.1.3. You can usually do this through the router configuration console. See help below:

http://portforward.com/routers.htm

Comment: I edited my question to mention that I had already done this.

Comment: Dude... i totally thought I had done that. It got screwed up some how, most likely my bad. Thanks!